# Python requests works in iPython, not in regular interpreter or in file

Tags: python, import, pip

I've run into the issue that when I import the requests module in iPython it works great however when I try to compile a file that uses it everything goes bananas. Similarly when I try to import requests in the standard python interpreter things go bananas as well.

Any ideas?

```
import csv, requests, re
```

Leads to

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sherpa_romeo.py", line 18, in <module>
  import csv, requests, re
ImportError: No module named requests
```

I'm thinking that I may have pip'd to the wrong version of python.

I installed with the command:
pip install requests

I ran the command pip list and it returned:

```
certifi (14.05.14)
Flask (0.10.1)
gnureadline (6.3.3)
ipython (2.4.1)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.7.3)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
oauthlib (0.6.3)
pip (1.5.6)
pokitdok (0.9)
requests (2.4.0)
requests-oauthlib (0.4.1)
sendgrid (1.1.0)
setuptools (5.4.2)
smtpapi (0.1.2)
unittest2 (0.5.1)
virtualenv (1.11.6)
Werkzeug (0.9.6)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

which includes requests so I'm confused on why it's not working.

Comment: are you in a virtual environment sth like `workon request-test`?

Comment: @ozgur I don't think so I use venv for when I build flask applications. Do you think that might have something to do with it?

Comment: I have the same issue. `import sklearn` give an import error in python, or when running `python file.py`, but in ipython it works fine! Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In the directory where you have the file that you compile, see if there is another file named "requests" and rename it

Comment: Nope that is not an issue. Don't have a requests.py in my directory. Thanks though